# Elasticsearch match on either a key name, or a key value

Tags: elasticsearch

suppose I have two indexed documents in my elasticsearch cluster --

```
{"APPLE": "TEST"}
{"TEST": "APPLE"}
```

Suppose I want to search on an `APPLE` term. What query would return to me both of these documents?

Comment: Asking Why you would want to build such a query: Keys are not content and should not be searched for matching terms. Even if this would be possible, you should build your schema according to your required search queries.

Comment: It's a product request. And it doesn't sound unreasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use match query to search for documents having `APPLE` as the field value, and [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) to search for documents having field `APPLE`. Try out this below query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "TEST": "APPLE"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "APPLE"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67048809",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "APPLE": "TEST"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67048809",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "TEST": "APPLE"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

You can query the field's existence with wildcard characters also.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "TEST": "APPLE"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "*APPLE*"        // note this
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's it! Can you query field existence with wildcards characters?

Comment: @JoeShmo please go through the updated part of the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Sure does, and I had tested it myself already. Thanks again.